# Aumentar caixa do menubutton

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Como podem ver na imagem, a última linha estourou o limite da caixa, onde eu posso aumentar a largura da caixa?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O código é o seguinte:

```
<p:menuButton id="documentos" value="#{messages['estada.modal.documentos']}" >
<p:menuitem>
                            <p:commandLink value="#{messages['estada.modal.emissao.relatorio.consolidado.programacao']}" id="relConsolidadeProgramacao"  
                                    style="text-decoration:none; margin-left:8px; padding-right:5px" immediate="true" process="@this" update="@form" oncomplete="emissaoRelatorio.show();">
                                <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{useCaseScope.idEstada}" value="#{row.id}"/>
                                <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{useCaseScope.estadaNavioIdentificador}" value="#{row.identificador}"/>
                                <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{useCaseScope.tipoRelatorio}" value="RC"/>
                                <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{useCaseScope.exibirUnidadeMedida}" value="true"/>
                            </p:commandLink>
                        </p:menuitem>
                    </p:menuButton>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode aumentar com css acredito que os comandos você pode verificar neste [site](https://code.google.com/p/primefaces/source/browse/primefaces/trunk/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/primefaces/menu/menu.css?r=3719) ou pode visualizar neste [site](https://code.google.com/p/primefaces/source/browse/primefaces/trunk/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/primefaces/menu/menu.css?r=5582).

Esses links são os css que o primefaces usa em suas versões anteriores,o primeiro é sobre o menuitem e o segundo sobre o menu button, aí neste caso você poderia settar o css para implementar o que deseja.

Por exemplo, o primefaces usa:

```
.ui-menubutton {
     display:inline-block;
     padding:0;
}
.ui-menubutton .ui-button {
     margin:0;
}
```